Set up a custom login page in a LWR Site
I'm trying to set up a custom experience page as a login page, using the option "Experience Builder Page" as Login Page Type in the administration page. However no matter how I configure the custom page, the only page that shows up here is "Login"

What I've tried:
-Completely new page with Login, Register, ForgotPassword components
-Using same contentlayout and themelayout
-Pages are all public
-Entering the page name manually does not save
Is there any requirement I'm missing to be able to use a custom experience page as login page?

Refer to this: Login Pages and  Configure Your Login Page

I have. These pages refer to the regular configuration and the use of standard pages. My question is about using a custom page.

Try to search your custom page name in the Lookup search shown in your screenshot.

I did. No page comes up except the standard Login one.

Make sure that the custom login page is published.

Everything is published.

Try to change the login page type in the dropdown.

Changed to default page, saved and changed back. Still no other page shows up except the standard Login.

@PabloCassinerio I couldn't get it to work on me site either but as a workaround, I can edit the standard login page. Maybe that helps you at least.
